# m:n relationship must have properties?

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I'm doing a E/R model for a project. I finished the ER model and, for me, all is okay. Maybe not perfect, but it's okay. When I gave the ER model to my teacher, he told me this:

> "the m:n relations MUST HAVE some properties"

He said if the `m:n` relationship doesn't have the properties it will be wrong. In my opinion `m:n` doesn't need forcer attributes to the relationship, but if you have someone that can fit in it, just put there.

What do you think? Who is wrong in this, me, or my teacher?

NOTE:

Reading again, it seems what he said was not due to my ER diagram, but was a general statement. The diagram I gave him doesn't have relations yet, so there where just entities and atributes.

Comment: Was the *"the m:n relations MUST HAVE some properties"* statement referring to the specific homework/problem/diagram or was it a general statement?

Comment: it was a general statment... thats why i get mad with that topic and thinked about post it on stackoverflow and know your opinions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Must" is too strong.  I can see where the JOIN table in an m:n relationship need not have attributes; those are common in my applications.

I can also see when they'd be useful.

I hate dogma in all forms.  Know the rules; know when to break the rules and why.  Your instructor would be far more educational and knowledable if they'd approach the issue that way.

Comment: I agree but (in defense of) the teacher, he may was referring to the specific ER diagram and given relationships/homework - which we have no clue about.

Comment: it's a open project. i can do the database of what i want... the problem is he doesn't view my relationships yet... but he said me if the m:n don't have an atribute he gonna qualified it as wrong because all m:n MUST have atributes (it's a final project not an activity to understand m:n relationships)